# No puede detectar nombres indefinidos al importar

Tags: python

Quiero hacer un problema simple con Pyomo pero al poner

```
 from coopr.pyomo import *
```

me dice:

> unable to detect undefined names

No sé cómo resolver esto, ¿alguien me podría ayudar?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que no es un error, sino una advertencia de tu editor, que debe de estar usando algún *linter* (posiblemente Flake8) para detectar malas prácticas.

La mala práctica aquí es usar `from coopr.pyomo import *`. Esta sintaxis se desaconseja por varias razones:

1. Hace difícil para otros (y para ti) leer y entender el código, ya que al usar un símbolo que haya sido importado de esa forma no se sabe de qué módulo vino.
2. Puedes tener *colisiones* al importar símbolos con el mismo nombre de módulos diferentes.
3. El *linter* no puede detectar (si usas esta sintaxis) si estás importando símbolos que luego no usas, y tampoco puede detectar si intentas usar un símbolo sin haberlo importado (pues podría formar parte de los incluidos en el "comodín"). De hecho, a esto último se refiere el error que has visto.

La sintaxis recomendada sería:

```
import modulo
```

y después cuando uses un símbolo de ese paquete, prefijarlo con su espacio de nombres.

También puedes usar:

```
from modulo import simbolo
```

para no tener que usar el prefijo. Esta sintaxis deja más claro qué símbolos importas (y por tanto pretendes usar) de ese paquete.

Por cierto que el paquete `coopr.pyomo` parece obsoleto. En la [ultima versión de Pyomo en Githuyb](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo) no aparece, y dice que ha sido renombrado a Pyomo.

Comment: si esta obsoleto cómo soluciono el problema? existe alguna guía?

Comment: Yo seguiría los enlaces del [repositorio de Github](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo) que es la versión más actual. Allí tienes enlaces a descargas, documentación, etc.

Comment: @PerdidaenPython Acabo de probar a instalar pyomo con `pip install pyomo` y ha ido bien. Después de eso, tu ejemplo se ejecuta sin errores (aunque no sé si hace lo que debería) cambiando el import inicial por `from pyomo.environ import *` (que sigue siendo desaconsejado por usar el asterisco, pero bueno).